# NodeJS child process not firing close event when writing to STDIN

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin, child-process, spawn

I am using the following code to spawn a child process that asks the user for input and then it should complete, but the `close` event is never fired.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const p = spawn('script', ['that', 'prompts', 'user', 'for', 'input']);

process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
  p.stdin.write(data);
});

p.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process closed with code ${code}`);
});
```

If I spawn a process that doesn't prompt for user input (like `ls´), the`close` event fires without any issue. I suspect something about writing directly into the child process's STDIN from the parent is preventing it from terminating correctly but I can't figure out why. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: This code works as is. Try it with 'bc' and type 'quit'. The problem is with whatever you're spawning not actually exiting under the conditions you think it should be exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I have written directly into child-processes over stdin and handled it but attaching a listener for 'finish' event on stdout of the child process. Perhaps it will apply to your use-case scenario, perhaps not.

If it helps you can read over the code I had used to implement it. 
[code here](https://gist.github.com/BrandKNY/cec0305e37f8067e7d28e2c8f13387fe).
Please note the code is a bit messy still, it was a rudimentary approach toward producing a module to allow child processes to run Linux commands using sudo privileges within a non-root parent process; in order to do this I needed a way to supply the password for sudo. The idea was to allow the password to be passed in from a configuration file, from stdin prompt, or resolved from a Promise asynchronously such as fetched from a database where it could be stored encrypted and potentially unencrypted along the way. Eventually I would like to revisit that code and re-write it much better, so what you see is just a proof of concept/experimenting. Also it is written in ES6+ (Arrow Functions, Promises, Classes, Constructors).